# Inline the out parameter in a method call

Tags: c#

When writing code I sometimes find it useful to return a bool value of successful and an out parameter of a code if needed. Or even using the `TryParse` functions and their respective out parameters.

A recent example of this was the following method signature:

```
private State GetTheStateOfClass1(Class1 o, out double confidence)
```

Here I have a method that finds the state of a `Class1` object and its corresponding confidence that the object does have that state.

This method is used when creating a new instance of `Class2` like so:

```
double confidence;
Class2 c2 = new Class2(GetTheStateOfClass1(o, out confidence), confidence, ...);
```

Is there a way that I can use an inlined out parameter like so:

```
Class2 c2 = new Class2(GetTheStateOfClass1(o, out double confidence), confidence, ...);
```

Comment: I propose `Tuple<State, double>` or `StateWithConfidence`. `out` parameters are already meh, but when you involve them in expressions where they are both set and used it's doubly meh. `new Class2(o.GetStateWithConfidence())` (this can be an extension method if necessary), or just `new Class2(o)`, leaving `Class2` to figure things out on its own, is a lot more readable. Subjective, of course.

Comment: In C# 7, [this should become possible, with exactly the syntax you propose](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/). Whether your final example is eventually going to compile (using the inlined parameter in the same statement as its declaration) is still an open question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh awesome is that confirmed yet? And can you post it as an answer if its confirmed?

Comment: It isn't confirmed and that's why I didn't post it as an answer. This is part of VS "15" preview 4, but it's happened before that things that were in a preview didn't appear in the final version, or not in exactly that form. When C# 7 is really out we'll now more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, this is impossible; the `out` parameter is required to be an actual variable in the caller's scope. That being said, a workaround would be to create an overload that does not use the out parameter as follows.

```
private State GetTheStateOfClass1(Class1 o)
{
    double confidence;
    return GetTheStateOfClass1(Class1 o, out confidence);
}
```